# I need to understand the physical Modbus network design

Tags: modbus, modbus-tcp, modbus-rtu-over-tcp

I am new to Modbus and I want to understand how the physical network can be set up.

Currently I register Modbus TCP devices as slaves one by one in this C1 device.
This works on ethernet, but I am not sure if I can communicate/discover RTU devices in device C1.

Is it possible via any gateway or router ?
If yes how will be the design of that network ?

Currently what I understand is like this,

Modbus TCP client (C1) <-> Modbus TCP gateway <-> Modbus TCP slaves/clients

Comment: Show some [mre] in your next question. So some code. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus

Comment: I want to understand the physical network connection for modbus devices.. there is no code as such right now. I have few questions in mind,

1. If I use Modbus TCP how will be the connection of devices ?
2. Will I need a gateway or switch for my network ?
3. Can I connect Modbus RTU to a Modbus TCP Master ?
4. What is the recommended network connection for TCP and RTU devices ?